# How to get true byte order with BufferedInputStream.read()?

Tags: java, datainputstream, bufferedinputstream

A server sends me an int according to:

```java
DataOutputStream stdOut = new DataOutputStream(myServerSocket.getOutputStream());
stdOut.writeInt(1);
stdOut.flush();
```

I try to read it from my client with:

```java
BufferedInputStream dIn = new BufferedInputStream(myClientSocket.getInputStream());
byte[] reception        = new byte[4]; // writeInt() writes 4 bytes
int status              = -1;

status = dIn.read(reception, 0, 4); 
// status = 1
// (int) reception = 0
```

I am waiting for 4 bytes to compute the sent Int.
However, it just receive 1 byte and deals with it without waiting remaining bytes.
Because I wait for 4 bytes, I tried this then:

```java
int count = 0;
while(count < 4) {
    status = dIn.read(reception);
    count += status;
    System.out.println("Read: " + count);
}*/
```

I see that it reads 1 byte then 3 bytes.

- Enventually, when I print the HEX result, I get: 00 00 01 00.
- It seems that it what sent like this (in order): 00 00 00 01
- And received in two parts: 00, then 00 00 01
- Which was stored like: 00 00 01 00.

That is why I do not get my int 1.

1. What is the purpose of read(bytes, 0, 4) if it does not wait for 4
   bytes?
2. How to get simply my 4 bytes in the true order?

Note: when the client uses DataInputStream, a readInt() works fine...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If DataInputStream has the behavior you need then use it.

Comment: 1. The 4 specifies the maximum number of bytes to transfer, as it clearly states in the Javadoc. 2.  Your read loop has a bug, which `readInt()` doesn't. Unclear why you aren't using the code that works, and that is symmetrical wih the sender.

Comment: I read on this forum that BufferedInput/OutputStream was faster. I wanted to try it to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `DataInputStream` and its `readInt()` method.

```
DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(myClientSocket.getInputStream()));
int status = dIn.readInt();
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work! In fact, I did'nt know the syntax to use, I used BufferedStream without DataStream...